# Net::Nessus::REST using API Keys vs. Session Token

Tags: perl, api, nessus

I have a perl script using the Net::Nessus::REST module.  Currently I'm using:

```
$nessus->create_session(
    username => $NESSUSUSER,
    password => $NESSUSPASSWORD
);
```

this bit of code to create a session token. This works great so long as my scans complete within 30 minutes. After 30 minutes the session token expires and I get this error message.

server error: Invalid Credentials at nessus.pl line 68

Unless somebody knows a way to set the timeout to something like 86400 seconds, I would like to use the API Access/Secret Key that I generate. The only problem I have is that I cannot find an example of how to list this with some bit of perl script using the Net::Nessus::REST module. Could somebody help me with the bit API Key of code that I could swap in for the create_session example above?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you peruse the local documentation within the [method's doc section](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Nessus::REST#$nessus-%3Ecreate_session(username-=%3E-$username,-password-=%3E-$password))? Apparently, it may provide insight. I don't have a Nessus server, so I can't view it myself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip StevieB, I checked these before posting and I don't see anything about API Keys, just token sessions. I'm hoping that I've overlooked something.

Comment: I found a way around the 30 minute timeout by changing the  xmlrpc_idle_session_timeout setting and restarting Nessus. In short, I can go back to using session tokens. But I'd still like to know how to use API Keys vs. session tokens.

Comment: Can't you just refresh the session? Or are _your scans_ one command and then it goes and does stuff on its own?

Answer (score 2):

It really is rather simple; you have to include a Http-Header "X-ApiKeys" in each request:

Java:

```
con.setRequestProperty("X-ApiKeys", "accessKey="+YourAccKey+";secretKey="+YourSecKey+";");
```

Curl:

```
curl -X POST -H 'X-ApiKeys: accessKey=YOURKEY;secretKey=YOURSECRET' -H 'Content-Type:application/json' 
    --data '{"scan_id":"21", "alt_targets":[127.0.0.1]}' 
-k "https://NessusServerIp:8834/scans/21/launch" | python -m json.tool
```

..This will do all the magic.

---

For more info check out the API-Docu [ -> https://YourNessusIP:8834/api#/authorization ] :

*API Keys
These keys are generated per account through Nessus.session: keys or Nessus.users: keys and can be used to authenticate without creating a session.
Add them to your request using the following HTTP header:*

```
X-ApiKeys: accessKey={accessKey}; secretKey={secretKey};
```

*Example:*

`curl -H "X-ApiKeys: accessKey={accessKey}; secretKey={secretKey}" https://{nessus-host}/scans`*